# Multiple geometries from one Geojson source without multiple layers

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I'm following this example:

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/multiple-geometries/

For each feature / shape on the map, they draw a new layer. However, I want to make "set" of features per Geojson I'm rendering on the map to be its own layer. Is it possible to group them somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mapbox GL, each [layer](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layers) is associated with exactly one "shape" (`circle`, `line`, `symbol`, `fill`, `raster`, or `fill-extrusion`). It is not possible to render multiple "shapes" per layer.

You can control which features are rendered in a particular layer using [filters](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#types-filter).

Does that provide any more clarity? Can you describe specifically what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thank you, this is what I ended up doing.